# Font changes between design time and runtime (VS 2010 and wpf)

Tags: wpf, visual-studio-2010

When I create a window or custom control with wpf inside Visual Studio the default font used is Segoue UI 12 (at least on Windows 7). When I execute the application the font really used is Verdana 13, a bit greater, so some signs are cut and the user experience is a poor formatting look and feel. Don't know how to change the default font inside VS 2010 and if it is the best way to achieve the goal of aligning what I see during the design phase and what the user will see at run time.
I checked for the word 'Verdana' in the entire solution and it was not found so I'm quite sure this weird behavior is not due to a style which is applied as a dynamic resource.

Thanks for any help

Filippo

Answer (score 1):

By default, WPF uses system font in runtime. If you want to always use Segoe UI, you can set FontFamily property to "Segoe UI".